# add a UIView above tableView problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have add a subView to  UITableView in my application,after adding, the tableViewCell still clickable,how to prevent this?pls help

Comment: Could you provide more information and more code?
Do you want to block all the events on the table while you're displaying the view (selection and moving)? Or block only the selection event when the cell is behind the view? Does your view cover all the screen?

Comment: ya i want to block all the events on the table like selection and moving.currently my view doesnt cover all the tableview, when drop down i still can see part of the tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your problem this time, if you can make the subview the size of the screen, then you just need to set userInteractionEnabled to TRUE on the subview.

Tested it with a simple UITableView and a UIImageView over it. If I disable the userInteractionEnabled then the willSelectRowAtIndexPath of the tableView delegate is called, if I set it to TRUE nothing happens.

Comment: i donot want my tableView not clickable at all time, jus when i add the subview above the tableView and it just unclickable. 
the problem i have is when i add a new view , the tableView was behind but still can click and link to corresponding view
the viewcontroller i used is tableViewController